# How do I compute tag of full associative mapped cache?

Tags: caching, mapping

I have a full associative mapping cache memory with globally 2^10 lines.
Each line is hosting 16 data.
The address bus a 32 bits.

How many bits are necessary for the TAG?

I think I have to make bus - the offset is it correct? how do I compute the offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is by subtracting to the adress bus the logarithm ofthe block. In this case so is 32-4=28.